# Android : adding transformed overlay on top of camera view

Tags: android, opencv, android-camera, android-view, android-overlay

In my android project I want to add an overlay (which is simple image with text on it) on top of the camera view.

The overlay is not simple rectangle but it is transformed at each camera frame.

What I'm looking for is kind of like image below:

[image]

I'm getting camera frame with OpenCV library (`CvCameraViewListener` and `CameraBridgeViewBase`).

My question is what is the best and fastest way to do this?

How can I transformed the overlay at each frame in the way as figure above shows.

Any help and suggestion is appreciated.